# Short-Circuit And Float

Tags: python, short, short-circuiting

Im trying to use short circuit in Python to print some data but my float didnt appear with 2 number after the dot despite i wrote .2f

```
((DidHourPlus == 1) and (StartWeek == 1) and (post == "r") and print("The daily salary is %2.f" %  ((hours - 8) * 35 + 8 * 30)))
((DidHourPlus == 1) and (StartWeek == 1) and (post == "s") and print("The daily salary is %2.f" % (1.20*((hours - 8) * 35 + 8 * 30))))
((DidHourPlus == 1) and (StartWeek == 1) and (post == "m") and print("The daily salary is %2.f" % (1.50*((hours - 8) * 35 + 8 * 30))))
```

Comment: Try `%.2f` instead of `%2.f`.

Comment: Its appear " The daily salary is 465.000000 " do you know why ?

Comment: Yes, it's because you didn't write `%.2f`. This is a simple typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a misuse of short-circuiting. Don't use `and` this way. Use `if` statements.

For two decimal places put the `2` after the decimal place: `%.2f` not `%2.f`.

```
if DidHourPlus == 1 and StartWeek == 1 and post == "r": print("The daily salary is %.2f" %  ((hours - 8) * 35 + 8 * 30)))
if DidHourPlus == 1 and StartWeek == 1 and post == "s": print("The daily salary is %.2f" % (1.20*((hours - 8) * 35 + 8 * 30)))
if DidHourPlus == 1 and StartWeek == 1 and post == "m": print("The daily salary is %.2f" % (1.50*((hours - 8) * 35 + 8 * 30)))
```

You can extract the repeated tests into a single `if`:

```
if DidHourPlus == 1 and StartWeek == 1:
    if post == "r": print("The daily salary is %.2f" %  ((hours - 8) * 35 + 8 * 30)))
    if post == "s": print("The daily salary is %.2f" % (1.20*((hours - 8) * 35 + 8 * 30)))
    if post == "m": print("The daily salary is %.2f" % (1.50*((hours - 8) * 35 + 8 * 30)))
```

Then extract the printout:

```
if DidHourPlus == 1 and StartWeek == 1:
    salary = None

    if post == "r": salary = (hours - 8) * 35 + 8 * 30
    if post == "s": salary = 1.20*((hours - 8) * 35 + 8 * 30)
    if post == "m": salary = 1.50*((hours - 8) * 35 + 8 * 30)

    if salary:
        print("The daily salary is %.2f" % salary)
```

Then extract the salary calculation:

```
if DidHourPlus == 1 and StartWeek == 1:
    rate = None

    if post == "r": rate = 1.00
    if post == "s": rate = 1.20
    if post == "m": rate = 1.50

    if rate:
        salary = rate * ((hours - 8) * 35 + 8 * 30)
        print("The daily salary is %.2f" % salary)
```

You could stop there, but if you want to get even fancier you could lookup the rates in a dictionary.

```
if DidHourPlus == 1 and StartWeek == 1:
    rates = {"r": 1.00, "s": 1.20, "m": 1.50}
    rate  = rates.get(post)

    if rate:
        salary = rate * ((hours - 8) * 35 + 8 * 30)
        print("The daily salary is %.2f" % salary)
```

In Python 3.8 you can tighten it up even further with an [assignment expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/).

```
if DidHourPlus == 1 and StartWeek == 1:
    rates = {"r": 1.00, "s": 1.20, "m": 1.50}

    if rate := rates.get(post):
        salary = rate * ((hours - 8) * 35 + 8 * 30)
        print("The daily salary is %.2f" % salary)
```

Comment: Yeah, I understand. My advice: don't.